# Fields "children" conflict because they have different arguments

Tags: jss, graphql

When trying to access the children of the different templates at the same level. We will be getting this error

***Fields "children" conflict because they have different arguments. Use different aliases on the fields to fetch both if this was intentional.***

[image]

```
Query=> children(includeTemplateIDs: ["{GUID}"]) {
    ... on Icon {
      name
      image {
        alt
        src
      }
      linkUrl {
        anchor
        linkType
        target
        url
        className
      }
    }
  }
children(includeTemplateIDs: ["{GUID}"]) 
  {
    ... on Menu {
      name
      linkUrl {
        anchor
        linkType
        target
        url
        className
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, we should aliases text to children at the same level and this applies to all the fields, items. Here in this example **SocialIcon** and **MenuList** as aliases.

```
 { SocialIcon: children(includeTemplateIDs: ["{GUID}"]) {
    ... on Icon {
      name
      image {
        alt
        src
      }
      linkUrl {
        anchor
        linkType
        target
        url
        className
      }
    }
  }
 MenuList:  children(includeTemplateIDs: ["{GUID}"]) 
  {
    ... on Menu {
      name
      linkUrl {
        anchor
        linkType
        target
        url
        className
      }
    }
  }
}
```